# Altair plots no longer displaying in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, altair

My Altair plots are no longer displaying in VS Code. Is anyone else having this issue? Matplotlib / pandas plots still show normally.

I used the simple bar chart example:

```
source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})
```

I can plot a pandas bar chart and get it to display:

```
source.plot.bar()
```

[image]

But I get no output when using Altair:

```
alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='a',
    y='b'
)
```

[image]

Comment: I have no problems with 1.59.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to call the chart, so first you need to save the chart as a variable and then call.

```
Chart1=alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
   x='a',
   y='b'
)
Chart1
```